# SELECT SUM not working in php code. How do I use it with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

The name of the table is "hit" and the name of the row that i would like the sum of is "amount" but my code is not working

```
 <?php 
        $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT sum(amount) FROM hits');
        if (FALSE === $result) die("Select sum failed: ".mysqli_error);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $sum = $row[0];
        print $sum; 

        ?>
```

The error i get back is "Notice: Use of undefined constant mysqli_error - assumed 'mysqli_error' in ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such `mysqli_error()` method available in PHP till now. There is `mysql_error()` you shouln't confuse with it.

The solution is

`if (FALSE === $result) die("Select sum failed: " . $mysqli->error);`

More [MySQLi Error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Thank you. i did both of your ways and got the same error "Select sum failed: Table 'hits.hits' doesn't exist" i dont have "hits.hits" typed anywhere in my code so im stuck.

Comment: What is your database name? Do you configured correctly? `$mysqli = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');`?

Comment: i mixed them up. my database's name is "hits" and the table's name is "hit"... i had the database's name instead of the table's name..! edit: also, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (FALSE === $result) die("Select sum failed: ".mysqli_error);
```

should be

```
if (FALSE === $result) die("Select sum failed: ".$mysqli->error());
```

Comment: ahh thank you John Conde. my mistakes are alwaaays obvious and then i feel guilty about making a whole post for it lol! thanks again

Comment: @John Conde, I don't see `mysqli_error()` method exists. Can you paste the link?